# Is this written in word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

Is [this](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2020/07/TangIncomp071620.pdf) written in Word ? Can I obtain a sample with the proper suffix here, so that I just download it, click it and modify it ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a PDF File, you can open this in word and convert it to word document so you can edit this

Comment: This works in Office 2013 and later versions. It may have certain issues (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/opening-pdfs-in-word-1d1d2acc-afa0-46ef-891d-b76bcd83d9c8), but for this document it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this written in Word?

Checking the properties of the document indicates that it is a pdf document that was created by Word. So yes, written in Word.

[image: IMG:]

> Can I obtain a sample with the proper suffix here, so that I just download it, click it and modify it ?

If you mean to download the Word document and modify it, I think you should ask the author to provide it to you and ask him the permission to modify it as doing it can be a violation of intellectual property.

Comment: How did you open that description table ? Also, what font is the text there beginning with "Tangible" ? I.e. which font should I select to obtain that output ?

Comment: @user2925716 Acrobat Reader

Comment: I mean how did you open "Document properties" with "Description" "File" "Title" "Author" etc. My "Properties" do not work, see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1569748/details-of-a-pdf-document).