# Details of a pdf document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

How can I open this window for a pdf document ?
"Properties" item do not work.

[image: IMG:]

Properties opens something more brief:

[image]

Comment: Which products are you using and where did you take these screenshots?

Comment: @harrymc I have downloaded [this](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2020/07/TangIncomp071620.pdf) file and I take these screenshots from another [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1569683/is-this-written-in-word/1569710#comment2391275_1569710). I use LibreOffice and Windows 8.1. I esp. need the file owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Acrobat Reader. After opening the file, on the menu click on File, then Properties. The Document Properties window will open.